# RethinkDB: Create Index on field in nested array (running into big data scenario)

Tags: rethinkdb

Here is an example document:

```
{
    "id": 12345,
    "links": [
        {
            url: "http://something.com",
            created: 1234567890987
        },
        {
            url: "http://somethingelse.com",
            created: 1234567891548
        },
        {
            url: "http://somethingweird.com",
            created: 1234567898555
        }
    ]
}
```

The `created` field is just a unix timestamp. I want to be able to run indexed queries on the `created` field contained in each item of the `links` array. I have no idea how to go about this (or if it's possible). As an example, this query is not even able to complete anymore since there are so many documents in the table (around 7million):

```
r.db('test').table('very_large_table')
  .filter(function(row) {
    return row('links').filter(function(link) {
        return link('created').ge(1425293715379) 
    }).isEmpty().not()
  })
  .count()
```

**EDIT** Since the dataset is so large, I abandoned the real-time query for an aggregation strategy. Now instead of trying to query this data as requested, we have message queues and data aggregation jobs which compact this data so it's already processed and super fast to query. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a multi-index on the `created` fields like this:

```
r.db('test').table('very_large_table')
 .indexCreate('links_created', r.row('links')('created'), {multi:true})
```

And use the index like this:

```
r.db('test').table('very_large_table')
 .between(1425293715379, null, {index:'links_created'})
```

See the documentation here: http://rethinkdb.com/docs/secondary-indexes/python/

Comment: Thanks @AtnNn! I saw the `multi` property in the docs but I couldn't figure out what the practical use of it was. Now I know!

Comment: So I did create the indexes (took a while). The table is up to about 8 million rows now. I tried this query (the timestamp is March 1st):

    `r.db('dev').table('really_large_table')
  .between(1425186000000, null, {index: 'multi_links_created'})
  .count()`

And it still hasn't completed :( Been about 3 minutes so far... any thoughts?

Comment: If the index doesn't fully fit into the cache, it might be loading things from disk. Are you using an SSD or rotational drive? Can you check the server logs (in the Data Explorer) for a message like "Automatically using cache size of X MB" and check if X has a reasonable size? You can override the setting by writing to r.db('rethinkdb').table('server_config').update({cache_size_mb: NEW_VALUE}).

Comment: One more thing: the query
`r.db('dev').table('really_large_table') .between(1425186000000, null, index: 'multi_links_created'}) .count()` actually counts the number of links that have been created after the given timestamp, not the number of documents. If there is one document that has multiple links created after the timestamp, that document will be counted multiple times by the query. You can change the query to `...between(...)('id').distinct().count()`, though that will not work if you have more than 100,000 new links. Let me know if you need these semantics for more links.

Comment: @DanielMewes The documents can have multiple items in the `links` array. Right now, the count on the table is about 8million, but that is the count of documents, not links. There are at least as many links as documents. As for you question about SSD, yes we are running with SSD drives. I believe the cache is around 5 GB (on a server with 64GB of ram). Just to let you know that `count()` query never finished. I let it run for about 3 hours...

Comment: Something definitely isn't right if that count query is taking more than three hours with just a couple million rows in the table.
Would you mind sending me an email to daniel@rethinkdb.com so we can investigate this further?
Is RethinkDB using CPU while the query is running?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the question: This is a performance issue. The query works, but because of the number of documents in your database, it's having a hard time executing that query.

I'd say you have two options: trying to optimize your query or changing the schema of your documents.

http://rethinkdb.com/docs/secondary-indexes/javascript/

**1. Optimizing your query**

It seems like the way you wrote your query works, but it could be more efficient. In your example, you go through all the links in every single document and run a `.ge` on every single one of them. Perhaps, you could get the `.max` or `.min` of all the links and then compare against that using `.ge`. I'm pretty sure this would be faster, but not sure if it would be fast enough.

```
r.db('test').table('rethink_question_timestamp_index')
  .hasFields('links')
  .map(function (row){ return row('links').max('created')('created') })
  .filter(r.row.ge(1425293715379))
  .count()
```

**2. Changing your schema**

If instead of having links inside of a document, you created another `link` table and then inserted the links there using a one-to-many relationship to the documents in `very_large_table`, then you could [create an index](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#index_create) on the `created` field which would speed up queries on links and then use a [`.join`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#eq_join) to join the links and their parent documents together.

From the RethinkDB website:

"Create a new secondary index on a table. Secondary indexes improve the speed of many read queries at the slight cost of increased storage space and decreased write performance."

---

**UPDATE**

@AtnNn is right. Creating a secondary index on the sub-property is the way to go!

http://rethinkdb.com/docs/secondary-indexes/javascript/

Comment: Thanks Jorge. You guys help a ton! Marked AtnNn's answer.